# Min. number of generators of a finite $p$-group is $\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}(G/G^p[G,G])$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, p-groups

> Prove that the minimum number of generators of a finite $p$-group $G$ is $\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}(G/G^p[G,G])$, the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

I know that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then $G^p[G,G] = \Phi(G)$, where $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$, and that if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then $\Phi(V) = \{0\}$, so we would have $$\Phi\left(G/\Phi(G)\right) = \{0\}$$

I also know that the Frattini subgroup of $G$ is the set of non-generators of $G$, i.e., $$d\left(G\right) = d\left(G/\Phi(G)\right)$$
where $d()$ dentoes the minimum number of generators.  But I'm not sure how to put this all together to prove what I need to prove.  Thanks.

Comment: Well $G/\Phi(G)$ is a vector space so $d(G/\Phi(G))$ is precisely the dimension of $G/\Phi(G)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. With what you said in the beginning, this is the dimension of $G/G^p[G,G]$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: OK, I think I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.  Thanks.